# Moving Platforms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

We are at very beginning of studying Unity, so we decided to create a mini-platformer. We've already made coins, platforms and character animation, but when we tried to animate a platform, a huge catastrophe appeared. The problem is that character can't stand on the platform. When the platform moves, he falls (it looks like there's no friction, but we tried to set one - it was helpless).
Maybe, we repeat the question, that have been asked before, but hope you'll help us to solve this paradox. Have a nice day ;)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class CharControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxSpeed = 10f; 
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
    private Animator anim;
    private bool isGrounded = false;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    private float groundRadius = 0.2f;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public Text scoreText;
    public float score = 0;


    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround); 
        anim.SetBool ("Ground", isGrounded);

        anim.SetFloat ("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        if (isGrounded && rigidbody2D.velocity.y != 0)
            return;

        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        if(move > 0 && !isFacingRight)
            Flip();
        else if (move < 0 && isFacingRight)
            Flip();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded && (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Joystick1Button0)))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 600));              
        }
    }

    private void Flip()
    {

        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
        if(col.gameObject.name == "Skull"){
            score++;
            Destroy (col.gameObject);
            scoreText.text = "" + score;
        }
        if ((col.gameObject.name == "dead"))
            Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
    }}
```

Comment: @adricadar We want a character to move a with a platform, to stick him to it.

Comment: this should work out of the box unless you have implemented your game in a weird way.

Comment: @Ewan Could you tell us how to do it right. We have been using unity for two days.

Comment: Sure, send me your code

Comment: @Ewan We only have code for the character http://pastebin.com/9mRWzwQ5 The platforms aren't coded, we only add rigidbody2D, box collider and unity animation to it.

Comment: I cant use pastebin, youll have to update your question with some code snippets and stuff

Comment: @Ewan code's been added!

Comment: does 'FixedUpdate' get called or can you remove it? Also take out the OnTriggerEnter2D. Does you character have a ridgedbody?

Comment: @Ewan Yes, we use FixedUpdate to move our character, And yes, character has rigidbody2D.

Comment: lose the Update and change the velocity setting to use forces instead

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Comment: it looks like on every FixedUpdate you are setting the velocity, this means nothing can move your character except the joystick input.

Comment: I suggets that instead you make your character a circle ridgedbody. when you get left/right input set the rotation of the circle as if its a wheel attempting to drive in the direction you want the character to move.

Comment: leave the rest for the physics engine to handle

Answer (score 0):

you need to set MovingPlatform is ParentObject of HoldPlayerPlatform.
check below images for that also

Here is Holding Player Script on Moving Platform.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HoldPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
   private GameObject target = null;
   private Vector3 offset;
   void Start()
   {
         target = null;
   }
   void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
   {
         target = col.gameObject;
         offset = target.transform.position - transform.position;
   }
   void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
   {
         target = null;
   }
   void LateUpdate()
   {
         if (target != null)
         {
             target.transform.position = transform.position + offset;
         }
   }
}
```

Here is image for setup HoldPlayerPlatform
[image: setup HoldPlayerPlatform]

Here is Setup for MovingPlatform
[image]